# It takes too long to shut down the Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2019

I set up Docker on Windows Server 2019. When I want to turn off containers, I have to wait too long on the console screen.

[image]

When I type and run a shutdown command, it stays that way for a long time, as shown in the picture.

**I wonder what this problem might be about. Thank you for your help in advance.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#extended-description), when you execute the command `docker container stop`:

> The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after
> a grace period, SIGKILL.

The command also supports [an optional flag `-t`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#options) which you can use to change the default grace period to reduce the time to send the `SIGKILL` signal. The default value is `10` seconds.

However, you should use this option carefully depending on the application running in the container as the application can get into unexpected state if it doesn't handle forceful termination carefully.

Optionally, you can also use [`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/#extended-description) command to directly send the `SIGKILL` signal if you want to terminate the container forcefully.

Answer (score 4):

When you use docker stop command `docker container stop <container_name>` and you can also pass the number of seconds before a container is killed by a `--time` flag.

Ex: `docker container stop <container_name> -t 1`: The command will wait `1` second as we gave the `-t 1` before the killing.

The default number of seconds the `docker container stop <container_name>` command will wait before the killing is `10` seconds.